# Approximation of characteristic function by smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Can we approximate characteristics function of an interval by a smooth function $f$ whose Fourier transform is compactly supported? If yes, how to prove that theorem? Could someone please refer me to the available results in this regard? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Approximate in what sense?

Comment: Take the Fourier transform, truncate it (to a sufficiently large, compact set) and invert. This will give approximation in $L^2$ at least.

Comment: Thanks. For your comment.